# Reallocating memory to 2D array element is not working C Language;

Tags: c

I am trying to reallocate memory for a 2D array element, not the full array But it's not working.

Note: I am new to the C language.

```
int** resultIndexArr = malloc(sizeof(int**) * 2);
resultIndexArr[0] = realloc(resultIndexArr[0], sizeof(int *) +sizeof(resultIndexArr[0]));
printf("%lu", sizeof(resultIndexArr[0])); // prints 8; but it should be 16;
```

Comment: `resultIndexArr[0]` hasn't yet been assigned a value, so passing it to `realloc` is undefined behaviour. Just use `malloc` again, but see next comment.

Comment: `sizeof` does not give the size of dynamically allocated memory. Please see the duplicate post for more details.